# jQuery remove row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Being relatively new with jQuery I hope someone could point me in the right direction on how to best remove a certain table row.

Source:

```
<table>
    <tr class="first">
        <td class="first b b-posts"><a href='edit.php'>1</a></td>
        <td class="t posts"><a href='edit.php'>Bericht</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first b b_pages"><a href='edit.php?post_type=page'>0</a></td>
        <td class="t pages"><a href='edit.php?post_type=page'>Pagina's</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first b b-cats"><a href='edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category'>1</a></td>
        <td class="t cats"><a href='edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category'>Categorie</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first b b-tags"><a href='edit-tags.php'>0</a></td>
        <td class="t tags"><a href='edit-tags.php'>Trefwoorden</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This being the bit I'd like to remove:

```
<tr>
    <td class="first b b-tags"><a href='edit-tags.php'>0</a></td>
    <td class="t tags"><a href='edit-tags.php'>Trefwoorden</a></td>
</tr>
```

I've tried using these next lines of code, which leaves me with an empty `tr`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(a) {
    a("tr td.b-tags").remove();
    a("tr td.tags").remove();
});
```

Comment: I've tried `jQuery(document).ready(function(a) { a("tr td.b-tags").remove(); a("tr td.tags").remove(); });`, which leaves me with and empty `tr`.

Comment: It leaves you with an empty `tr` because you did not target the `tr` for removal.  You only targeted `td.b-tags` _within_ `tr`.  Please edit your question with what you've tried to eliminate a legitimate reason for down-votes.

Comment: Just updated my question containing my own trial and error (which I should have done when asking). Also, thank you all for the enormous amount of replies. I'll get back on this asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eq` based on the row index you want to remove.
Note that the index is zero-based.
So `eq(3)` removes the fourth.

```
$('table tr:eq(3)').remove();
```

Or based on child `td` class.

```
$('.b-tags').parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's always the last element, you could use this:

```
$('table tr').last().remove();
```

Alternatively, if it's the fourth element, use `:eq()` in your selector:

```
$('table tr:eq(3)').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.b-tags').parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td.first.b.b-tags').closest('tr').remove();​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uz3E5/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

$("first.b.b-tags").parent().remove();

Comment: You are missing `.`s in your class names.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this, if you want remove the last row in a table:

```
$("table tr").filter(":last").remove();
```

[Here is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/rkSr4/)